# Gallery opens and closes right after, when trying to read a file from internal Storage

Tags: android, android-intent, android-internal-storage

Im using this method to save a image to my files folder in the app internal storage.

```
public static String saveToInternalStorage(Context ctx,Bitmap bitmapImage){
        Date date = new Date();
        File mypath = new File(ctx.getFilesDir(), "ATM_"+date.getTime()+".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(mypath);
            bitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) {
                    fos.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return mypath.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

In another option of the app i want to open the image in the android gallery and i try to do so with this code

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
    // set flag to give temporary permission to external app to use your FileProvider
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    // generate URI, I defined authority as the application ID in the Manifest, the last param is file I want to open
    File file =  new File(path);
    if(file.exists() && file.isFile()) {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, file);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
```

I also have this declared on my manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>

    </provider>
```

And my file_provider_paths looks like this

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<files-path name="files" path="/"/>
```

What happens is that when i press the button to open the image on the gallery , i see the application picker for that file type , and when i choose gallery it opens and closes right after.

**Question 1**: Why is this happening?

**Question 2**: How to i open the gallery to show all of the images on the "files" folder from internal storage?